# pyramid with "*" and "." in c++

Tags: logic

I need to do a pyramid with stars and dots. The first half of the code is doing correct but the other half is doing wrong. I have tried this.

The input is: size=4 and n = 7
the output is:

```
*...
**..
***.
****
.***
..**
...*
```

I want it to be

```
*...
**..
***.
****
***.
**..
*...
```

```
#include < iostream >

using namespace std;

int main() {
  int size, n;

  cin >> size;
  cin >> n;

  for (int R = 1; R <= size; R++) {
    if (R > n) {
      break;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
      if (i > R) {
        cout << ".";
      } else {
        cout << "*";
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  for (int R = 1; R <= size - 1; R++) {
    if (R > n) {
      break;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
      if (i > R) {
        cout << "*";
      } else {
        cout << ".";
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: if `size == 4` and `n == 7` the condition `if (R > n)` can never be true because your `R` is always `<= size`

Comment: And why did you switch the conditions for printing `*` and `.` in your second loop. You still have to print `*` first, and then `.` ...

Comment: @derpirscher I dont understand. If i do: if(R<n) it does not print anything

Comment: you can remove that `if (R > n)` entirely. It doesn't have any effekt in your code .. I don't know what that `n` is even good for . You don't access it at all

Comment: @derpirscher how to I fix the other half in the pyramid